# Jquery plugin for scrolling and dragging content inside a div horizontally with easing effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

I am looking for a plugin which can provide same functionality given at

http://satorisan.com/en/shop

I have found some plugins but some are specific  for mousewheel and other with dragging or swiping.

So my requirement is to display products same like the reference link.

That i have multiple products to display, and i want functionality to swipe the products horizontly, on mousemove and scrolling with easing effect.

So can anybody please help where i can find this type of plugin or how can i work for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The functionality your are talking about is called a carousel.
There is a jquery plugin for that called [jcarousel](http://plugins.jquery.com/jcarousel/).